# sed find replace special characters inside xml

Tags: xml, sed, replace, special-characters

I have this tag inside a XML file:

```
<content type="html">bla bla text...&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
&lt;a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~randomurl;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~randomimg" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~randomsrc height="1" width="1" alt=""/&gt;</content>
```

My target is to remove the complete url/special character part. It should look like this:

```
<content type="html">bla bla text...</content>
```

I want to do this since it breaks my XML parser. Any ideas how to achieve it?

I tried sed but wasn't successful yet :(

Comment: can you extend your input for multiple nodes?

Comment: Try to provide a more precise description of what you want to remove, e.g. "everything within the content of the `<content>` element from the first `<` character to the end". Presumably there are multiple documents that you want to process (otherwise you could do it by hand) and we need to know what they have in common: one example doesn't tell us that.

Comment: @MichaelKay It is a RSS feed which has to be parsed on a cron job. Changes should be sent through a messaging app.

In the feed are many <content> parts with content described as above. They're all in one file. I just need the pure text parts for processing :)

Comment: Why not correct the cron job to produce well-formed XML?

Comment: I transform an existing RSS feed to use this data for my own messages. I have to use this format.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `sed` to process it

```
$ cat test.xml
<content type="html">bla bla text...&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;&lt;a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~randomurl;img rc="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~randomimg" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~randomsrc height="1" width="1" alt=""/&gt;</content>

$ sed -e 's/&[^<]*//g' test.xml
<content type="html">bla bla text...</content>
```

This would remove the digits from `&` to the first `<` it hit.

Comment: Thanks! This looks good so far. It has a few linebreaks in the end from the original file. So I have to see what I can do about it but this helps alot.